# Clickable MC function - AS2

Tags: flash, function, actionscript-2, movieclip, clickable

I need a bit help with this problem. I have some objects in a little game and I want them to be shooted down based on the animation insede of them.

This funkction works just fine:

```
coke2.onPress = function () {
    if (coke2.shootable && shoot){
        snimek = "anim" + Math.ceil((Math.random()*3));
        coke2.gotoAndPlay(snimek);
        plusScore(100);
        coke2.shootable = false;
    }
}
```

but, when I have multiple objects its not efficient. I thought the followingfuncktion will work well but when I click on the can nothing happens.

```
function canClicked(can){
    if (can.shootable && shoot){
        snimek = "anim" + Math.ceil((Math.random()*3));
        can.gotoAndPlay(snimek);
        plusScore(100);
        can.shootable = false;
    }
}

coke.onPress = canClicked(this);
```

PS: don't mind the stuff insede of function. There's not problem in there...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself by inserting it in other function, but still i dont know why my idea wasn't working...

```
coke.onPress = function(){
    canClicked(this);
}
```